# pytest: When using the keyword option (-k) a directory style string is not handled

Tags: python, keyword, pytest, backslash

I am currently using pytest to automate my test suite. I have tests spread over several directories like below:

```
|-Root
|   |-Dir1
|   |   |-Test1
|   |   |-Test2
|   |   |-Test3
|   |-Dir2
|   |   |-Testa
|   |   |-Testb
|   |   |-Testc
|   |-Dir3
|   |   |-TestI
|   |   |-TestII
|   |   |-TestIII
```

I would like to be able to run tests in a set of directories by excluding others. Some of the directories have similar names like "test_set_1" and "test_set_1_extended". I'd like to exclude "test_set_1" but keep "test_set_1_extended" so I'd need to use the full path as a keyword. I've noticed when using the keywords (-k option) that pytest doesn't handle directory structure strings as an argument well.  For instance, if I try windows style

```
py.test -k "not (root\dir1 or dir2)"
```

I get a syntax error:

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

On the other hand if I try unix style

```
py.test -k "not (root/dir1 or dir2)"
```

I get a ZeroDivisionError:

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Things I've tried include:
Enclosing the directory string in single or double quotes:

```
py.test -k "not ('root/dir1' or dir2)"
py.test -k "not ("root/dir1' or dir2)"
```

Using separate '-k's':

```
py.test -k "not root/dir1" -k not dir2)
```

Using a current directory '.'

```
py.test -k "not (./root/dir1 or dir2)"
```

Escaping the slash:

```
py.test -k "not (root\\dir1 or dir2)"
py.test -k "not (root\/dir1 or dir2)"
```

None of these have solved the problem. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get pytest to handle my path string correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Why not save yourself the workarounds and just use unique markers for your different test groups, and use

```
py.test -m "not extended"
```

This way test/directory/module names can change and nothing breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I am working with a very similar setup and I have been able to reproduce the behavior you are describing (`pytest 3.4.0`, `python 3.6.4`).

I have found a workaround that might be useful to you depending on your exact layout). Basically, I am using `and` instead of the path separator.

Therefore `py.test -k "not (root/dir1 or dir2)"` becomes `py.test -k "not ((root and dir1) or dir2)"`. If you do not have any more `dir1` path elements under `root/dir1`, both expressions should be equivalent.

Since the behavior of expressions including `/` seems somewhat inconsistent (`py.test -k root/dir1` works as expected), it might make sense to file a bug.